# jQuery / Colorbox - Pass one variable to <div id='inline_content'>

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I know nothing about jQuery and have been trying to get this going for over a week. It looks like I need professional advice. On our church site we have a page containing member birthdates. If I could the member id number into the inline_content block, I could get all the data I need with some reference. Ex. $memberid=$_REQUEST['memberid']; Here is what I'm using:

blanknew.php (page title)

Lots of PHP code

head
  link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/colorbox.css" 
  script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" /script>
  script src="_js/jquery.colorbox.js" /script>
  script
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content", width:"300px"});
      });
  /script
/head
body
  Here I have a table with member names (and memberids)

td nowrap="nowrap" align="left"  a class="inline" href="#inline_content?memberid=' . $ID .'"' . $fname . '/a /td;
         (I'm pretty sure this is wrong)

```
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
      <?php 
echo $_REQUEST['memberid']; (this gives me nothing)
?> 
      </div>
</div>
```

I'm not lazy but I just don't know where to begin. If someone could give me the code I need and exactly where to put it, I would be very grateful. (I can't say I'm impressed with the auto formatting of my code - it's bad enough already)

Comment: Please fix your code so that it's readable.

Comment: You'll need to add the class of `inline` back into your <a>'s in addition to the `memberid` class (just a space between them). Or, you could change the click function to capture on the class `inline` as well; i.e., `$(".inline").click(function() {...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you have available to you or what your end goal is, but here are some thoughts I had.

You can place script functions like this towards the top of the page IF they are wrapped in the `$(document).ready()` function. What it sounds like you want to do is put member IDs into the div you showed. You could set up an event for each member on the page so that when they are clicked on wherever you have their 'member id' stored could get displayed in your inline-content. (did you mean to hide the inline content with `display:none`? You could apply that to the inner div with the same outcome -- and if `$_REQUEST['memberid']` is populated, you won't see it while `display:none` is there unless you have an action that changes that property.)

Here's an idea that might work for you:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // Specify a class for all your members and then 
       $(".some_clickable_element_with_member_id").click(function() {
           $("#inline_content").html( $(this).attr("id") );
           return false; // if you don't want the click to go anywhere (assuming you're using an <a> tag.
       });
    });
</script>
```

Are you trying to have a table set up so that there are hidden attributes of the member ids which you want to pass to a subsequent page via a hyperlink? You don't need jQuery for that. You could just build the links in php with the memberid as part of the query string to the destination page. For example:

```
<a href="processThisMember.php?member_id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <?php echo $fname; ?>
</a>
```

**Edit**

You probably want to wait to become more familiar with jQuery and HTML before trying to integrate a plug-in. Read up on the jQuery documentation for [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) and once you understand or partially absorb how to find elements and operate on them you're going to be in a much better place to solve this and future scenarios.

To access the person's id for your links just ask for the id:

```
$(this).attr("id");
```

`$(this)` changes depending on the context. I am assuming you're operating on the link `$(".memberid").click(function() {`. At that point, $(this) refers to the hyperlink that was clicked on.

To access the name, just ask for the html(); this gets the contents between the opening  and the closing

```
$(this).html();
```

To put it all together,

```
$("#inline_content").html( $(this).attr("id") + " " + $(this).html() );
```

I'm not familiar with colorbox so I don't know how you should or are supposed to be able to pass values to it. I suggested giving the href of # but it looks like *that* was how the colorbox was getting activated. Change your links back to an href of

```
<a href="#inline_content" id=...></a>
```

Leave the class and the id there and hopefully you'll be able to take these ideas and generate the behavior you're looking for. There's still the possibility that you should leave the href as to how you had it when you asked this question but hopefully this will get you to where you want to be. Work with changing one thing at a time and watching how the behavior changes.

Remove the script tags merely containing `$("#inline_content").html();` that wasn't how I intended for you to use that information.

When you change the  back you should see your colorbox pop-up again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your promp answer. The page I'm working on is http://jfbc.net/blanknew.php .  I get the id# and name of the last guy in the list right now. It's pretty messy right now but this is the code:

Comment: Hi @Bill; I see that you have added my ideas to the page but you haven't added mark-up that could use it. You need to add the class="memberid" to all your people hyperlinks. Then, if you don't want to change the jQuery code, you need to give the <a> tags the id of the member id's attribute. Like this: `<a class='memberid' id='1115'>Robbie Taylor</a>`

Comment: If you want to see the code, tell me where to send it. This site gives me too many hassles...

Comment: Congratulations; it looks like you've populated the #inline_content with the id's when a member is clicked. Now if you want the colorbox to still fire, then remove the `return false;`. It looks like the colorbox plug-in already keeps the click from 'going anywhere'.

Comment: <body bgcolor="#938a79">
    <!--<p><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a></p>-->
    <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
          <?php 
    echo $_REQUEST['memberid'];
    echo $_SESSION['temp'];
   ?> 
         
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: I commented out the return statement

Comment: Maybe you should replace it with an `alert($("#inline_content").html());` so that you can see what is going on.

Comment: The memberids are showing up in the alert box now. Now if I could just to output them to the box ... that was the whole point - I wanted the member's contact info to pop up in the box - rather than go to a different page.